# Place div on top of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried all the solutions I have found on the new trying to get this div to sit on top of the image.

We have a background image, and as you can see from the image below are four words Eversoft, TruSoft, Solarmax and Active Family.

[image]

These four words need to be moved up into the boxes on the picture, but I can get the CSS right, this is how my page is constructed

```
<div class="row">
   <img src="~/Content/Images/Mobile-BackGround-new-2.png" class="img-responsive" style="position: relative" />
   <div id="stainMasterLinksContainer">
    <div id="stainMasterLinksTop">
        <a href='@Url.Action("Eversoft", "Eversoft")' style="color: #934991;" class="GothamFont" id="Eversoft"><b>EverSoft</b> <small><sup>®</sup></small></a>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Trusoft", "Trusoft")' style="color: #f7acb7" class="GothamFont"><b>TruSoft</b> <small><sup>®</sup></small></a>
    </div>
    <div id="stainMasterLinksBottom">
        <a href='@Url.Action("Solarmax", "Solarmax")' style="color: #ffe600" class="GothamFont" id="Solarmax"><b>SolarMax</b> <small><sup>®</sup></small></a>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ActiveFamily", "ActiveFamily")' style="color: #dc1e33" class="GothamFont" id="ActiveFamily"><b>Active Family</b> <small><sup>™</sup></small></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm currently using this CSS for the stainMasterLinksContainer

```
#stainMasterLinksContainer {
padding-top: -40%;
font-size: 15.5px;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Offhand, I can see one issue: `padding` can't be negative, use `margin` instead.

Comment: why not just set the image as a background image?

Comment: @jmore009 I tried setting the div back ground as the image, but I'm unable to use img-responsive which results in the image not being responsive viewing on a mobile phone, it also results in a white border being around the image when viewed on a mobile, so I have to come back to this approach allowing me to use img-responsive

Comment: did you try `background-size: cover`?

Comment: @jmore009 Yes, I spent the vast majority of yesterday going over the web trying to resolve this.

I tried many different solution with no success, so I've resulted back to doing it this way for the time being.

Comment: This isn't a particularly responsive design, nor perfect. But maybe it can give you some idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/f5L2e60z/1/

Comment: what's contained in your "stainMasterLinksTop" CSS?

Answer (score 2):

It CAN be done.  Here's one way:

```html
<img src="http://practicalaction.org/images/sea-of-ducks-300.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px"/>

<div style="background-color:blue;position:relative;left:80px; top:80px; width:50px;"> Hello</div>
```

Comment: but let's say the image was enclosed in a parent DIV, wouldn't this throw positioning off inside of that DIV?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  (I did and the answer is no).   In any case, that wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: I did try..  https://jsfiddle.net/dwqd5aot/ and it did collapse the parent DIV, throwing off positioning.